# Unknown Object in my rendering

Tags: rendering, light

In my very first rendering I have an unknown object in my rendering image. its not found on any layer and I cant finde any unknown axis or objects on my rendered layers. Its a white circle behind a cup. could it have something to do with the light?

[image]

Comment: it would be helpful if you would upload the scene somewhere.
and no, i dont believe its a lighting artifact.

Answer (score 3):

Alt+H has shown me the hidden circle.

Problem solved